# Firebase using signOut, it only sign out the first user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'm testing a sign out endpoint from postman, I login the first user, log in a second user and then signout the first user, try to signout the sencond but it returns null, like the second user no exist.

Is that a correct behaviour?

I'm using customToken to sign in the users.

Code to sign in:

```
 firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token);
```

Code to sign out:

```
return firebase.auth().signOut()
.then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
  console.log("no ok")
});
```

EDIT 1:

Can I do something like this?

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser:

return firebase.auth().signOut(user)
.then(function() {
//Sign-out successful
}).catch(function(error) {
//An error happened.
});
```

Comment: I would say that behavior is correct, any other site would work the same way. (not allow two users a session simultaneously)

Comment: I wonder, should Firebase create a session for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it looks like, because when you logged in the second time, it replaces first authentication user by the second user.

And if you send `sign out`, it removes the second user authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andrew. So how can I test the sign out function? Is ok to test with postman or should I use another method to test the sign out? Is this a normal behaviour or I am putting the pieces wrong?